# correlation matrix from text file

Tags: r, matrix, data.table

I am trying to make correlation matrix from a text files what I have. I want to get the correlation values from these files.

text file what I have

```
[56] "[1] \”values “”of the                                                                                                          
[57] "[1] \”e”xamples                                                                                                              
[58] "[1] \”dummy “”lines                                                                                            
[59] "[1] \”testing”                                                                                                                     
[60] "[1] \"Correlation Values\””                                                                                                         
[61] "[1] \"Correlation between XXX and YYY: 0.7054 (0.0429)\""                                                                            
[62] "[1] \"Correlation between XXX and ZZZ: 0.601 (0.0289)\""                                                                             
[63] "[1] \"Correlation between YYY and ZZZ: 0.6434 (0.0306)\""                                                                            
[64] "[1] \”Finished\””                                                                                        
[65] "[1] \”testing “”linne                                                                            
[66] “test”                                                                                                                                          
[67] “test “again
```

The matrix will look like

```
      XXX       YYY      ZZZ
XXX   1        0.7054    0.601
YYY   0.7054   1         0.6434
ZZZ   0.601    0.6434    1
```

I understand that there is some regex technique involved, but think its too advanced for a novice like me. I can get the lines what I want from the file using the following, but still not able to workout the way to extract those numbers and put in a matrix.

```
mm[grep("Correlation Values”, mm, value = FALSE) + c(1:3)] ## m is the above file that I loaded.
```

To add the complexity to it the variables and number change in all files. Say this is the case of 4*4 matrix

```
[95] "[1] \"Correlation Values\””                                                                                                                                 
 [96] "[1] \"Correlation between XXX and YYY: 0.7054 (0.0429)\""                                                                                                    
 [97] "[1] \"Correlation between XXX and ZZZ: 0.601 (0.0289)\""                                                                                                     
 [98] "[1] \"Correlation between XXX and CCC: 0.0178 (0.0281)\""                                                                                                    
 [99] "[1] \"Correlation between YYY and ZZZ: 0.6434 (0.0306)\""                                                                                                    
[100] "[1] \"Correlation between YYY and CCC: 0.0103 (0.0286)\""                                                                                                    
[101] "[1] \"Correlation between ZZZ and CCC: 0.0174 (0.0202)\""                                                                                                    
[102] "[1] \”Finished\””
```

Comment: it would be helpful to know how generic a solution you are lookng for.  For example, will you know the names of the variables in advance? Will you know the number of variables (is it always three?).   Or do you just want to do a one time thing on this file?  Also are there really those pairs of double quotes at the ends of the line?

Comment: @Elin This is exactly how the file looks like.  I do have many files like this, but the structure is exactly same like what I have shown here. 

 Wont be knowing the variables in advance. But the variables and the numbers of variables change (I want to capture all lines between "[60] "[1] \"Correlation Values\””                                                                                                         
" and  [64] "[1] \”Finished\”” )

Comment: Also does the text file literally include the numbers such as [56]?

Comment: @Elin Yes it does.

Comment: @Elin So there are cases like this

Comment: sorry too long to post it here. Will post in question

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a start anyway ... not elegant but step by step gets you to just having the relevant information in a list.  I put your file in a file called sofile.txt.

```
# read the messy file
filedata <- readLines("../bugs/sofile.txt", warn = FALSE)
# get rid of lines you don't need.
preline<- grep("Correlation Values", filedata, fixed = TRUE)
postline<- grep("Finished", filedata, fixed = TRUE)
filedata <- filedata[(preline+1):(postline-1)]
# just keep the important parts of the strings
filedata <- substr(filedata, 33, nchar(filedata)-13)
filedata <- sub( ":", "", filedata, fixed = TRUE)
filedata <- sub( " and", "", filedata, fixed = TRUE)
# split them up and make a list
filedata_list<- strsplit(filedata, split = " ")
# put it into a matrix 
new <- Reduce(rbind, filedata_list)
# extract the variable names
names <- unique(c(new[,1], new[,2]))
#create a matrix of NAs with the right dimensions and names.
corrmat <- matrix(nrow =length(names),  ncol = (length(names)), dimnames = list(names, names))
```

Then you would work on replacing the NAs. Which you could do by working your way through the list to assign the values.

Again ugly as anything but will get you started.

```
for (i in 1:length(names)){
 corrmat[filedata_list[[i]][1], filedata_list[[i]][2]] <- filedata_list[[i]][3]
 corrmat[filedata_list[[i]][2], filedata_list[[i]][1]] <- filedata_list[[i]][3]
 corrmat[i, i] <- 1
}
```

Comment: Someone else will show a way to do it with the tidyverse that's maybe nicer.

Comment: Hi Elin, thanks for taking this.  Can I know what you are doing in filedata <- substr(filedata, 33, nchar(filedata)-13) ?

Comment: just thinking if the [96] line numbers change the things that it will pick ? So if I guess it correct we are picking XXX and YYY: 0.7054 there ?

Comment: Maybe something like this ? gsub('^.*between\\s*|\\s*\\(.*$', '', filedata)

Comment: Hi, the substr()  is picking the characters from 33 to 13 below the end.  This was from counting how long the unwanted strings were since in the filed those lengths were all the same.    Yes you could do it with gsub, something like that.